# protractor, browser is closed before testing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor, cucumber, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using protractor with Javascript and I need to test a login form. When I launch the *config.js* file, I see the browser opens with the url of the login page on loading. After loading I think that my *stepdefinition.js* file doesn't send the keys to the form, because the browser is closed immediately.

I used timeout `90*1000`, `browser.sleep`, `browser.pause`, `browser.wait`, but it didn't work. I have the `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` too, because it is a site without angular.

**config.js:**

```
const path = require("path");
const jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
const Reporter = require("../support/reporter");

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub",
  capabilities: {
    browserName: process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || "chrome",
    'chromeOptions': {
     //'args': ['--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile'],
      'args': ['--disable-web-security', '--user-data-dir=~/.e2e-chrome-profile']
    }
  },
  framework: "custom",
  frameworkPath: require.resolve("protractor-cucumber-framework"),
  specs: ["../features/footer/*.feature"],
  // resultJsonOutputFile: "./reports/json/protractor_report.json",
  onPrepare: function() {
    var chai = require('chai');
    chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    chai.should();
    global.expect = chai.expect;
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
    require('babel-register');
    Reporter.createDirectory(jsonReports);
  },
  cucumberOpts: {
    strict: true,
    format: 'json:./reports/json/cucumber_report.json',
    require: ["../stepDefinitions/footer/*.js", "../support/*.js"],
    tags: "(@Tag1Step1 or @Tag1Step2 or @Tag1Step3)"
  },
  onComplete: function () {
    Reporter.createHTMLReport();
  }
};
```

**stepdefinition.js:**

```
Given('I am on a mywesbsite page', function (next){
    browser.driver.get('https://myofficialrrwebsite.com/test/login.html');
    browser.sleep(5000);
    var bn_field = element(by.css('input[aria-labelledby="userNumber-label"]'));
    var fn_field = element(by.css('input[aria-labelledby="firstName-label"]'));
    var ln_field = element(by.css('input[aria-labelledby="lastName-label"]'));
    bn_field.clear().sendKeys('QWWWKD');
    fn_field.clear().sendKeys('Alex');
    ln_field.clear().sendKeys('Black'); 
    element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'September')).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('option', '09')).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('option', '1976')).click();
    var check_on_ter = element(by.id('checkbox'));
    check_on_ter.click(); 
    var button_login_el = element(by.css('button[data-linktext="Login"]'));
    button_login_el.click();
    browser.sleep(5000);
  next();
});
```

Can someone help me solve this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you have tried

Comment: Can you share your `config.js` and that `stepdefinition.js` you mention?

Comment: Hi @davidrv87! Thank you for ur answer. I edited my question with the informations you asks. Hope you may help me to solve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Hi @davidrv87. Do you have some advices?

Comment: The problem is that the browser will crash immediately after executio. how can I do?